# Making a courier tracking app in android studio using firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is how my database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI0Pn.jpg)

So in the app when i enter the number and click the search button the location should be displayed.
How should i do this?

Comment: have you tried orderbyChild("number").equalTo([your input number]);
using query should achieve what you want

Comment: DatabaseReference myquery = (DatabaseReference) mDatabase.orderByChild("number").equalTo(trackno.getText().toString());
                tv.setText(myquery.getKey());

I tried this but the app crashes

Comment: please post the code including the declaration for the DatabaseReference here, I think your query is incorrect from your code

Comment: search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                DatabaseReference myquery = (DatabaseReference) mDatabase.orderByChild("number").equalTo(trackno.getText().toString());
                tv.setText(myquery.getKey());

Comment: private Button but1,leave,search,features;
    private EditText trackno;
    private TextView tv;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Update");

        trackno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trackno);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

Answer (score 0):

[Android retrieve data from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Try this:
`Query searchQuery=mDatabase .orderByChild("number").equalTo(trackno.getText().t‌​oString());
searchQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener{
public void onDataChange, public void onCancelled
});`

Please see the documentation from firebase regarding get the value from dataSnapshot

Comment: I cannot figure out how to use onDataChange and onCancelled
That's why i was using direct query

Comment: that is very simple, you can     `tv.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)); ` under onDataChange, it is very easy to understand, try go through some video and documentation and  you will know how easy it is

Comment: [Youtube Video Sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTk7q3f-t0I) , this is simple as shown in the video

Comment: The app is still crashing after this tv.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));

Comment: can screenshot here what is the error message? so that I can know more.

Comment: when i enter the number in my mobile application and click the search button then the application just crashes and shuts down , there is no output.

Comment: [Picture sample](https://i.imgur.com/xbPpCd1.png)
click over the Android Monitor there will show what is the error line to cause your apps crashes, check through there

Comment: my fault, try put the loop for it to retrieve the specific number from the data as below   
    `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
for(DataSnapshot children:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
tv.setText(dataSnapshot.child(number).getValue(String.class)); }}`

Comment: Not crashing but still no output. https://imgur.com/a/eO0bW (This is before doing anything).
https://imgur.com/a/liGlL (And this is after entering the number and hitting search)

Comment: can screenshot your latest code over here? I just want to double check it :)

Comment: almost there, now you change to tv.setText(children.child("number").getValue(String.class));

    hope will success~~

Comment: Thank you man so much. I have been at it for over a week and not able to do it. Thank you for all your time. You the man :) . I literally screamed when i saw the output.

Comment: it works?? congratz to you, I can tell you firebase is much fun than this, explore it more and read through the documentation.. give it a try

Comment: Yes , it worked. I will do study more about it and again thank you very much for your help and time.